# MS Access 2010: create multiple week records based on 1 one price record

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Can you please help me to solve following problem:
I've got table1 with 5 fields: ProductID, price, startWeek, endWeek, numWeeks;

```
xx ProdID xx price xx startWeek xx endWeek xx NumWeeks
   Prod1       $15       1           3           3
   Prod2       $20       2           4           3
```

I need to create another table2 to record price by ProductID on a weekly basis, so each Product would have the number of records for each week, like that:

```
Prod1 week1 $15,
Prod1 week2 $15
Prod1 week3 $15
Prod2 week2 $20
Prod2 week3 $20
Prod3 week4 $20
```

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question appears to be off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. Please [edit] your question to describe in detail the problem you are having with ***your*** code and include a [*minimal* example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

[TEST SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b32b6/1)

First, I will create a table for weeks. It is usually know as tally table or number table.

You can create one via VBA, but I wanto to kept simply (long, but simply)

You must run this code just one time.

```
create table weeks(weekNumber int, weekName varchar(10))
insert into weeks 
select 1, 'week1'
union all
select 2, 'week2'
union all
select 3, 'week3'
union all
select 4, 'week4'
union all
select 5, 'week5'
union all
select 6, 'week6'
union all
select 7, 'week7'
union all
select 8, 'week8'
union all
select 9, 'week9'
union all
select 10, 'week10'
union all
select 11, 'week11'
union all
select 12, 'week12'
union all
select 13, 'week13'
union all
select 14, 'week14'
union all
select 15, 'week15'
union all
select 16, 'week16'
union all
select 17, 'week17'
union all
select 18, 'week18'
union all
select 19, 'week19'
union all
select 20, 'week20'
union all
select 21, 'week21'
union all
select 22, 'week22'
union all
select 23, 'week23'
union all
select 24, 'week24'
union all
select 25, 'week25'
union all
select 26, 'week26'
union all
select 27, 'week27'
union all
select 28, 'week28'
union all
select 29, 'week29'
union all
select 30, 'week30'
union all
select 31, 'week31'
union all
select 32, 'week32'
union all
select 33, 'week33'
union all
select 34, 'week34'
union all
select 35, 'week35'
union all
select 36, 'week36'
union all
select 37, 'week37'
union all
select 38, 'week38'
union all
select 39, 'week39'
union all
select 40, 'week40'
union all
select 41, 'week41'
union all
select 42, 'week42'
union all
select 43, 'week43'
union all
select 44, 'week44'
union all
select 45, 'week45'
union all
select 46, 'week46'
union all
select 47, 'week47'
union all
select 48, 'week48'
union all
select 49, 'week49'
union all
select 50, 'week50'
union all
select 51, 'week51'
union all
select 52, 'week52'
union all
select 53, 'week53'
union all
select 54, 'week54'
union all
select 55, 'week55'
```

Then the solution is trivial:

1-create table2, run just one time

```
create table table2(ProductID varchar(10), weekName varchar(10), price int)
```

do the work

```
    insert into table2
    select a.ProductID, w.weekName, a.price 
    from table1 a inner join weeks w 
    on a.startWeek<=w.weekNumber and a.endWeek>=w.weekNumber
```

get results

```
select * from table2
```

Results:

```
ProductID   weekName    price
Prod1       week1       15
Prod1       week2       15
Prod1       week3       15
Prod2       week2       20
Prod2       week3       20
Prod2       week4       20
```

[TEST SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b32b6/1)

Comment: I don't have Access to check it, let me know if it need any tuning http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b32b6/1